# Input amount in unit with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I want to transform this input in unit, for example now if I type 10 it calculates 10 cents, I want that when I type 10 it will answer me with 10€

```
<b-form-input id="amount_input" type="number" v-model="form.contract.reward_cents" :state="validate(form.contract.reward_cents)"/>
        </b-form-group>
```

How can i do with vuejs?